# Number of faces of plane Graph

Tags: graph-theory

How do i begin this proof?

Let $G$ be a simple connected triangle-free plane graph with at
least three vertices. Prove that $f \leq n-2$.

Comment: Every face of such a graph is bounded by at least four edges. Try to use this to show $2f\le e$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $G$ is triangle-free, the degree of each face is at least $4$. Since the sum of the degree of all faces is equal to twice of the number of edges, we have 
$$\tag{1}2m\geq 4f.$$
where $m$ is the number of edges in $G$, and $f$ is the number of faces in $G$. Now combining $(1)$ with [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula), you will get the result.

Comment: Do i substitute 2m >= 4f in v-e+f=2 ?

Comment: Yes. But I use $m$ for the number of edges, but in the wiki page, they use $e$ for the number of edges.

Comment: Got it: v-2f+f<=2 -> v-f<=2 -> f<=v-2